# Compare time between a log file and an image file

Tags: c#, .net, readfile, exif

I have 1000's of images and more than 100,000 lines of log files. I need to check if there exists an image that is associated with each unix time in log file. To do this, I first read thru all the images and stored time information in an array. Then I read thru all the lines of the log file, split each information (lat, long, time) and stored them in an array. Finally, I am taking one time element at a time and checking if it matches with image time array. If no match is found, I get the time from log, get lat and long from the same array and write it to a text file. But the overall process takes very long time. I am looking into efficiencies on how to make this process faster.

```
        var fileList = Directory.GetFiles(imageLocation, "*.jpg");
        //Array that will store all the time information obtained from image property
        double[] imgTimeInfo = new double[fileList.Length];
        int imgTimeCounter =0;
        foreach (var fileName in fileList)
        {
            x++;
            string fileNameShort = fileName.Substring(fileName.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
            richTextBox1.AppendText("Getting time information from image " + x + " of " + fileList.Length + " : " + fileNameShort + Environment.NewLine);
            richTextBox1.Refresh();
            using (var fs = File.OpenRead(fileName))
            {
                //create an instance of a bitmap image
                var image = new Bitmap(fs);
                //get the date/time image property of the image
                PropertyItem property = image.GetPropertyItem(36867);
                System.Text.Encoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
                string valueFrmProperty = encoding.GetString(property.Value);


                //Format the value obtained to convert it into unix equivalent for comparison
                string valueCorrected = valueFrmProperty.Split(' ')[0].Replace(":", "/") + " " + valueFrmProperty.Split(' ')[1];
                var unixTime = ConvertToUnixTimeStamp(DateTime.Parse(valueCorrected));

                imgTimeInfo[imgTimeCounter] = unixTime;
                imgTimeCounter++;
                //It is very important to dispose the image resource before trying to read the property of another image. image.dispose frees the resources or else we get 
                //outofmemoryexception.
                image.Dispose();
             }
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Images done.");
        richTextBox1.AppendText("Fetching time information from log files..."+Environment.NewLine);
        richTextBox1.Refresh();
        int counter4Time = contentBathy.Length / 6;
        //assign counter for lat,long and time 

        int timeCounter = 3;

        for (int i = 0; i < counter4Time; i++)
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText("Searching time match with image files..." + Environment.NewLine);
            richTextBox1.Refresh();
            double timeValue = Int32.Parse(contentBathy[timeCounter]);
            //Looks for values that is +- 3 seconds different in the image file.
           if (Array.Exists(imgTimeInfo, a => a == timeValue || a == timeValue + 1 ||  a == timeValue + 2|| a == timeValue+3
                ||a == timeValue-1|| a== timeValue-2||a == timeValue-3))
            {                    
                File.AppendAllText(@"c:\temp\matched.txt", "Lat : " + contentBathy[timeCounter - 3] + "  Log : " + contentBathy[timeCounter - 2] + Environment.NewLine);
                richTextBox1.AppendText("Image with same time information found. Looking for another match."+ Environment.NewLine);
            }
            else
            {
                //richTextBox1.AppendText("Time did not match...Writing GPX cordinates..." + Environment.NewLine);
                //richTextBox1.Refresh();
                File.AppendAllText(gpxLocation, "Lat : " + contentBathy[timeCounter - 3] + "  Log : " + contentBathy[timeCounter - 2] + Environment.NewLine);
            }

            if(timeCounter < contentBathy.Length-3)
                timeCounter += 6;
         }
    }
```

Comment: which part takes long? I guess it's parsing (loading...) the images, right?

Comment: Loading image is actually not so bad. I tried with 3000 images and it is not taking that long. Comparison of the values between array elements is taking longest.

Comment: Try using a sortedlist (`System.Collections.Generic.SortedList`) instead. It will probably do a much better job at confirming existence,

Comment: The code is incomplete which makes it not make sense. contentBathy doesn't exist and counter4Time isn't explained. The code provided doesn't actually do what you claim it does (compares log lines to image meta data), that logic is entirely missing.

Comment: @Safari Jones, I do not think more than the above listed is necessary to understand the situation. Please read the code clear fully to find what counter4Time is, where it is declared and how it is used. The above code does everything I claim as comparison is done inside of second for- loop. I am just looking for efficiencies here. So, I am not sure what you mean by entire logic is missing.

Comment: @Amit, I cannot sort the array as I need to keep track of their original occurrence as their position is associated to other array contents. I solved the issue by using dictionary and associating one array element as the key and other associated values of arrays as dictionary values. It works perfect in my case. But thank you!